# Spring MVC Request body error handling

Tags: spring, http, spring-mvc, error-handling, bad-request

While using `@RequestBody` `StreamSource` found out, that if xml in request body in not valid `StreamSource` throws an Exception(resulting in 400 Bad Request) and i'm not able to handle it(tell client what is bad).

Is there a way to handle such exception?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general You can catch exception in Spring MVC that way:

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleMyException(Exception  exception) {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/errors/404");
    modelAndView.addObject("message", exception.getMessage());
    return modelAndView;
}
```

You can map it to any exception time and redirect user to any page with any mesage.

Alternatively: you can return it in `@ResponseBody`:

```
  @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
  @ResponseBody
  public String handleMyException(Exception  exception) {
      return exception.getMessage();
  }
```